# TCL check for only whitespace

Tags: tcl, whitespace

I am building a code to add user inputs into a file, but **i want to catch an event where users input only whitespaces and nothing else**. How do i do that? Currently i am hardcoding " " and "  " which will catch if users entered one whitespace or two whitespace, but i believe there is a better solution than mine.

**Proc to insert user input into text file**

```
proc inputWords {entryWidget} {
set inputs [$entryWidget get]
$entryWidget delete 0 end
if {$inputs == ""} {
.messageText configure -text "No empty strings"
} elseif {$inputs == " " || $inputs == "  "} {
.messageText configure -text "No whitespace strings"
} else {
set sp [open textfile.txt a]
puts $sp $inputs
close $sp
.messageText configure -text "Added $inputs into text file."
}
}
```

**GUI code**

```
button .messageText -text "Add words" -command "inputWords .ent"
entry .ent
pack .messageText .ent
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To accept whitespace strings of arbitrary length, including 0:

```
string is space $inputs
```

To accept whitespace strings that aren't empty:

```
string is space -strict $inputs
```

The result is true (=1) or false (=0).

Documentation: [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: This is the canonical method of testing for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression like {^\s+$}, which matches beginning of string followed only by one or more whitespaces (space or tab) up to the end of string.  So in your example:

```
elseif {[regexp {^\s+$} $inputs]} {
  .messageText configure -text "No whitespace strings"
...
```

If you want to check for all whitespace *and* empty strings in the same expression, use {^\s*$}.

See http://wiki.tcl.tk/396 for more information about regular expressions in TCL.  If this is your first exposure to regular expressions, I'd suggest looking for a regular expression tutorial online.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, you'd like to trim off leading and trailing spaces off the user-input, you may trim the string and check for zero-length. Performance-wise, this is better:

```
% set inputs "    "

% string length $inputs
4
% string length [string trim $inputs]
0
% 
% time {string length [string trim $inputs]} 1000
2.315 microseconds per iteration
% time {regexp  {^\s+$} $inputs} 1000
3.173 microseconds per iteration
% time {string length [string trim $inputs]} 10000
1.8305 microseconds per iteration
% time {regexp  {^\s+$} $inputs} 10000
3.1686 microseconds per iteration
% 
% # Trim it once and use it for calculating length
% set foo [string trim $inputs]
% time {string length $foo} 1000
1.596 microseconds per iteration
% time {string length $foo} 10000
1.4619 microseconds per iteration
%
```